# Update Query taking long to run

Tags: mysql, query-performance, subquery

I need some assistance with a query I am using (MySQL) to update another table. When running the nested query, the query runs in less than a second. But as soon as I include the update part, it takes hours to run. The query I am using is as per the below:

```
UPDATE sys_reference.outlet_reference OUTREF LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    store_code 'storeCode'
,   LEFT(header_value,20) 'CoOrds' 
FROM 
    am_data_warehouse.am_headers 
WHERE 
    action_date = CURDATE()- 1 
AND header_field_id IN (3641, 4937)
) GPSCO 
ON OUTREF.store_code = GPSCO.storeCode 
SET OUTREF.gps_coordinates = GPSCO.CoOrds
```

Below is the structure of the table that is being updated:

[image: MySQL Table]

Comment: What are your keys and indexes on both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sub-query isn't doing you any favors here. I *think* you can rewrite it to elimiate the sub-query.

```
UPDATE
    sys_reference.outlet_reference AS OUTREF
    INNER JOIN am_data_warehouse.am_headers AS GPSCO ON OUTREF.store_code = 
GPSCO.storeCode
SET
    OUTREF.gps_coordinates = LEFT(GPSCO.header_value,20)
WHERE
    GPSCO.action_date = CURDATE() - 1
    AND GPSCO.header_field_id IN (3641, 4937)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, ran your suggested update on the query and my data was updated in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @LeonClaassen You're welcome. Check that there's an index on am_data_warehouse.am_headers.storeCode. If there isn't, you can speed the query up even more by adding one on that column.

Comment: Also, `INDEX(action_date, header_field_id)`.